# Upload JavaScript/HTML based app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

When I go to the [Heroku dashboard](https://dashboard-next.heroku.com/apps), the options for creating an app includes Node.js but no JavaScript. Does it mean to upload my locally created JavaScript/HTML5 app to Heroku, I have to select Node.js or there is another way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku hosts applications. If you want to host a javascript/HTML5 web client application you will need a server that serves the files. An easy way to make this work on Heroku is to create a Node.js app and write a simple node server that will return your javascript and html files for the client to use. A nice simple library for creating a web server is [express.js](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just to be sure if I understand it completely- I have to create a Node.js app (possibly using express.js) which will serve as a web server and I have to upload this app to Heroku. This will enable me to host my JavaScript/HTML5 client app on the server I have just created. Did I miss anything?